# Add OpenCL CL/cl.h path to existing Make file

Tags: c, makefile

I am trying to successful execute a make file that comes from a new crytpo-coin called Sia Coin. It can be found here [Sia Coin GPU Miner](https://github.com/NebulousLabs/Sia-GPU-Miner). It's relatively new and so some stuff requires more manual installation. I was getting the following error on Ubuntu 16.04 when using the make file. `CL/cl.h` was missing, and I was able to install and it is located at `/usr/include/nvidia-361/CL/cl.h`. However, when I ran the make file I still get errors so I think I need to include this path someone in the Make file, the problem is I am not familiar with make files at all. Below is the Make file I need to edit to include the path for compilation:

```
ifeq ($(shell uname -s),Darwin)
    CC ?= clang
    LDLIBS += -lcurl -framework OpenCL
else
    CC ?= gcc
    LDLIBS += -lOpenCL -lcurl
endif

CFLAGS += -c -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -O2

TARGET = sia-gpu-miner

SOURCES = sia-gpu-miner.c network.c

OBJECTS = $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(SOURCES))

all: $(TARGET)

%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o $@ $<

$(TARGET): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(LDLIBS)

clean:
    rm -f $(TARGET) $(OBJECTS)

.PHONY: all clean
```

Any help toward solving this problem is greatly appreciated.

Edit:
A new message I am getting  now adding

```
CFLAGS += -c -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -O2 -I /usr/include/nvidia-361
```

is now:

```
-lOpenCL -lcurl /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Two files did compile:

```
sia-gpu-miner.c
network.c
```

But I don't know enough to know why the -lOpenCL is not found. No ld directory exists in that directory location in the error if that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
 CFLAGS += -c -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -O2
```

to

```
 CFLAGS += -c -std=c11 -Wall -pedantic -O2 -I /usr/include/nvidia-361
```

Comment: It's returning this now:

cc -o sia-gpu-miner sia-gpu-miner.o network.o -lOpenCL -lcurl
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lOpenCL
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: It's the same problem with library paths. Somewhere there should be an OpenCL library -- it might be named something like libOpenCL.a or .so -- look for what else installing OpenCL put on your drive.  Then add `-L /the/dir/where/libOpenCLis` to LDLIBS. Read `man ld` to learn about this option.

Comment: An easier way is to symbolic link it using ln -s if you don't want to edit the actual file